# How to copy the name of file or folder in the current directory in terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

When I type `ls` in terminal, I see what files I should select but it is very annoying to select them one by one. Is there any fast way to do it (except patterns)?

Comment: Select to do what?

Comment: What exactly you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that with standard software, but there are other simple and helpful tricks.

1. If you start typing a file name, you can press tab and the file name will be autocompleted.
2. If you drop a file into a terminal window, its path will be entered.
3. You can also quickly arrive in your destination folder by `right-click → Open in Terminal` in Nautilus. If you're using an older version of Ubuntu than 15.04, you'll need to install `nautilus-open-terminal` via `sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal` first. The other 2 shortcuts should work on any current version of Ubuntu.

Comment: There is no way to do that? Don't say "No way" if you're using Linux.

Comment: @A.B. I added "with standard software".